# RpcError from application code while cypress testing

Tags: vue.js, cypress, proto, grpc-web

I have a vuejs application which uses grpc-web and proto.
I am integrating cypress in my application for automation testing.

I am having an issue when running the cypress test the API call returning error, but when I am running the application directly in browser its working fine for the same API call.

I have checked all the request parameter and url all same.

[image]

I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should intercept the request and check the headers, maybe it's an auth problem.

Comment: Please also review [Getting error: code: 2 message: "Http response at 400 or 500 level" #769](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/769) and linked [Why is envoy proxy required? #347](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/347)

Comment: Any solution for this problem as of now?
I am using a similar protocol with Angular.

Comment: @vedantsali as far as I was not able got solution so I was moved to playwright which have support of RPC.